# Multiple term frequency vectors with one index

Tags: solr, lucene, elasticsearch

I have an application with many different document types. Each type has its own corpus and I don't want that they will affect each other.

For example, if one type contains many occurrences of the term X then I don't want that this will lower the IDF score of X in other types.

I know that this can be achieved using multiple indices but I have many types and some of them contain low number of documents. Hence an index per each type will have bad performance impact.

Is there any way that I can have a unique terms vector for each type with one index?

I didn't choose any search engine implementation yet, so I will appreciate answers for Elasticsearch and/or Solr.

Comment: Creating separate indexes for the terms you wish to keep entirely separate does seem like the logical route.  Am I correct in thinking that you only wish to search a single type with any given query?  What operations do you expect to see poor performance from in that situation?

Comment: Although I have searches that occur within single type, I also have searched that should run on all types.
I'm afraid from the performance of second case but mainly I'm afraid from the amount of hardware that I will need in order to support 100k indices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Elasticsearch, you would need to have each type in a separate index to avoid the term vectors from one type influencing those from another.

By default, Elasticsearch assigns each new index 5 primary shards (where each shard is a Lucene instance). For your smaller types, you can create the index with just a single primary shard:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/user/?pretty=1'  -d '
{
   "settings" : {
      "number_of_shards" : 1
   }
}
'
```

### UPDATE

Regarding your question about performance. Search happens on every involved shard in parallel, so the performance really depends on how much hardware you have and how big your shards are (and of course how complex your queries are).

It is difficult to estimate quite how performance will be impacted by multiple indices without testing out your use case and data. That said, ES is built for distributed search and performs very well in this scenario.

### UPDATE 2

The field `name` across different types in the same index will contain the terms in that field from all types, thus polluting your term frequencies.

However, an approach you might try is to just use different field names in different types, for instance, instead of using the field `name` for `user` and `product`, use `user_name` and `product_name`. The term frequencies will then relate to just that field in that type. The doc frequencies will obviously take all docs into account, but seeing that is a global effect, it shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: Do you have any estimation about the impact of having few thousands of indices with one shard on search performance (I will need to look for an item across all indices) and on the required hardware?

Answer (score 0):

You can always tune the IDF by reducing or eliminating its effect.

You can start with the [Custom Similarity](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrPlugins#Similarity) class.
This would allow you to modify the IDF calculation.

Check the [lucene DefaultSimilarity](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/trunk/lucene/src/java/org/apache/lucene/search/similarities/DefaultSimilarity.java) class for reference which is the actual implementation.

Comment: I do want IDF influence and current similarity scoring is good for me. The problem is that the docFreq that I get is across all documents. 

I can't manipulate the docFreq because I don't have a-prior knowledge of the terms frequency in each type and to manage the term frequency by myself sounds to me like a bad idea.

Comment: then maintaining the data in separate index is the only option and am sure it would not be bad for performance

Comment: From your experience, having thousands (maybe even more than 100k) of indices wouldn't affect the search overhead and will not require much more hardware too support it?

Comment: 100k documents unless having a very rich set of content would not occupy more then a couple of GBs in the index at the max. So i don't see that as an issue.